# Google Maps JS API equivalent of URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just realized that I cannot call directly on a URL from my AngularJS application due to CORS. Therefore, I expect I will have to use the Javascript API.

The following link provides me with the data I want:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' + myPosition.lat + ',' + myPosition.lng + '&rankby=distance&key=' + key  + '&sensor=false&type=clothing_store
```

However, I cannot figure how to achieve the same using the Javascript API. I found [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) in the documentation, but I do not need a map - just the names and coordinates of the nearby stores.

How can I get a hold of the same data using the Javascript API?

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got a Google Maps for JS API Map Key, you can do [a Places query](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) from the server side. Note, however, that you're limited to [1000 queries per day](https://developers.google.com/places/usage).

You can probably do this directly in your client and avoid CORS issues, but here's how I've done it previously using PHP:

```
<?php
    function ReturnEmpty()
    {
        // Something's wrong, return an empty set.
        echo '{"d":[]}';
    }

    $q = (isset($_GET["query"])) ? $_GET["query"] : 'NULL';


    if( $q == "" )
    {
        ReturnEmpty();
    }
    else
    {
        // I'm showing the "textsearch" option, but there is also a "nearbysearch" option..
        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query="
                . urlencode($q)
                . "&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY_HERE";

        $json = file_get_contents($url);

        $data = json_decode($json, true);

        echo $data;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nearbySearch(request, callback)` method on `google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)`.

In your case, the `request` should have a `location` (that contains the lat and lng) and a `radius`.

There are code samples [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests).

Comment: That still requires a `map` object, which I don't have